# Android Mainactivity doesn't show activity_main.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, android-imageview

After I changed some of my app design at the `activity_main.xml` and launch the app the `MainActivity` class design doesn't change.
I tried to change the design after I changed the working space from tablet to android phone and the design doesn't fit on the phone the image views are too large and they fill all the phone screen any suggestions how to make it fit within the phone?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_1"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.flagsgame.MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start_btn"
        android:layout_width="295dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/start_game" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/reguler"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:text="Classic Mode"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/reguler"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/reguler"
    android:layout_below="@+id/reguler"
    android:text="Time Attack Maddness" 
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "Flagss Game" ;//יצירת טאג למשחק לשימוש בםונקציות כמו exception

Button start;
Button time;
Button reguler;
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //List<Flagss> arrAdd= new ArrayList<Flagsss>();

    start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start_btn);
    time = (Button)findViewById(R.id.time);
    reguler = (Button)findViewById(R.id.reguler);
    start.setOnClickListener(this);
    db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    creat_rows();
}

/*
//קבלת התמונות
private void pic_view(String pic2) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //Log.d("Result from pic function " , pic2);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    String uri ="@drawable/";
    uri += pic2;
    int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());
    Drawable res= getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(res);

}*/

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    start.setVisibility(start.INVISIBLE);
    time.setVisibility(time.VISIBLE);
    reguler.setVisibility(reguler.VISIBLE);

    //Intent s = new Intent(this,ClassicMode.class);
    //startActivity(s);

    reguler.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cm = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ClassicMode.class);
            //Intent c = new Intent(MainActivity.class ,ClassicMode.class);
            startActivity(cm); 
        }
    });

    time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent tm = new Intent(MainActivity.this,TimeAttack.class);
            startActivity(tm);
            Log.d(TAG, "inside time");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is your `acivity_main.xml` in the default layout directory?

Comment: Are you saying your changes don't take effect when you change something in xml then run again?

Comment: has not closed his RelativeLayout tag. Done know if its a copy paste error or what because IDE should have shown it

Comment: yes is dont take effect is stays the same , nana what you mean?its in the directory i tried to delet and rebuild it dosent help

Comment: Try to clean and build your project again then run. If you are using Eclipse, this happens

Comment: Also, close your RelativeLayout tag.

Comment: yes iam using eclipse

Comment: its closed i didnt copy till the end hh

Comment: Ok, did you do what I suggested yet?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you have kept activity_main.xml file in the correct layout directory. It is possible that you might have changed it for another kind of layout. So verify all the activity_main.xml within your project.

Comment: Ive one activity_main and is in the res-layout

Comment: if possible post your project screenshot here.